# Why does this typing issue occur?

Tags: types, dafny

I am trying to write a program in Dafny, here is a part of the program:

```
method GenerateAllIndexSubsets<T>(q: seq<T>) returns (res: set<set<nat>>)
    ensures res == AllIndexSubsets(q)
{
    if |q| == 0
        { 
        assert |q| == 0;// if's guard
        // ==>
        assert {} == AllIndexSubsets<nat>([]);
        assert q == [];
        assert {} == AllIndexSubsets(q);
        res := {};
        assert res == AllIndexSubsets(q); // postcondition
        }
    else
        { 
            assert |q| != 0; // !(if's guard)
            var res0 : set<set<nat>> := GenerateAllIndexSubsets<T>(q[1..]);
            assert res0 == AllIndexSubsets(q[1..]);
            res := res0;    
            assert res ==  AllIndexSubsets(q[1..]); //GenerateAllIndexSubsets postcondition with q[1..]
            var index : nat := q[0];
            var res1: set<set<nat>> := (set x | x in res0 :: x + {index});
            assert res1 == AllIndexSubsets(q) - AllIndexSubsets(q[1..]);
            assert res0 == AllIndexSubsets(q[1..]);
            assert res1 == AllIndexSubsets(q) - res0;
            // ==>
            assert res0 + res1 == AllIndexSubsets(q);
            res := res + res1;
            assert res == AllIndexSubsets(q); // postcondition
        }
    assert res == AllIndexSubsets(q); // postcondition
}
```

on the line `var index : nat := q[0]` i am getting the following issue:

> type does not agree with element type seq (got int)

Why am i getting this and how can i fix it now and not get it again in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`q` is a sequence of elements of type `T`, so `q[0]` has type `T`. But you are trying to assign it to a variable of type `nat`, which is incorrect.

(The reason the Dafny error message mentions `int` instead of `nat` is that `nat` is defined to be a subset of `int`, so in order to check whether something is a `nat`, Dafny first checks that it is an `int`, which fails here.)

Comment: Thanks for th comment, can i assgin to a varriable of any type a value of type T? because if i want to work with the elements in q how can i do it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but you could say `var x : T := q[0]` for example. Does that do what you want?

Comment: Yes i know i can do that but if for example i want to multiple this element can i do it? because i do not know it's type ( if it is 'nat' or 'int') all i know it is type T so what actions i can do on it?

Comment: You can't do much to it, but that's kind of the point. What would it mean to multiply it by something if T was some arbitrary user-defined class, for example?

Comment: So what is the main purpose of it? iteration (in this case because we have sequence of type <T>)?

Comment: `T` is a type variable that stands for an arbitrary type. The point of type variables is to support code reuse rather than having to reimplement a function for each type you want to use it at.

As an aside, to my eye, it looked like what you meant to write was `var index := 0`, initializing the `index` to zero. Zero is an index, but `q[0]` is not an index, it's an element.

Comment: I just realized that you are possibly confused about the notation `seq<T>`. That is the type of "sequences of `T`s". So it's a list where each element has type `T`. You can access various elements using the indexing notation `q[i]` (if `q` is a sequence). Here `i` is an index into the list. Indices always have type `int`. To emphasize, the `T` is the type of elements, not indices.